# Is there an easier way to update Swype?

Tags: updates, swype

I currently have the Swype beta installed on my EVO - not the pre-installed one that comes with the newer updates, the actual beta from their site. I noticed yesterday that if I launch the Swype Installer it will check for updates to itself, then download and install the new version for me. This is nice, since it is not distributed in the Market.

However, I can't seem to find the same functionality in Swype itself. The Installer doesn't check for updates to the actual keyboard, and it just greets me with the "Congrats! Swype is installed!" screen after launch (even after updating). The only way I can figure out to update Swype at this point is to:

1. Find out if there's a new version somehow (Google, Swype's website, etc)
2. Uninstall Swype
3. Reinstall Swype

Is there an easier way to do this? It seems odd that they have no update feature built in since they deliberately chose to distribute Swype outside of the Market, but if such a feature *does* exist I have no idea where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of Swype beta (or at least the version before the most recent version) is a bit more self-sustained.

All I had to do when I updated was to go to the Swype installer app.  It had an update for itself.  After updating, it then presented an option for me to update Swype and stepped me through the process, including disabling, updating, and then re-enabling Swype.

Now the old way of updating Swyped used to be you had to uninstall the current version and it's installer, then re-install the installer, then re-install Swype.  It seems as if they have improved on this former method (that often had me raging because it wouldn't generate the license file correctly).

Comment: Hm, maybe mine will start doing this correctly now that I have the most recent version of both Swype and the installer. I was going from 2.17.xx to 2.29.xx. Thanks!